# How to programmatically create a stack panel that can be accessed by all subroutines

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am new to programming, I want to create a stack panel programmatically by the click of a button (that is anytime the button is clicked a new stack panel is created), and I should be able to access this new created stack panel from various subroutines in the program.

This is my code behind:

```vb
Class MainWindow

Private sub MyItems_Click(sender As Object, E As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyItems.Click

Dim NSP as new stackpanel()
StackPanel.children.add(NSP)

End sub

Private sub ThisPanel_Click(sender As Object, E As RoutedEventArgs) Handles This Panel.Click

Dim TXT as new textbox()
NSP.children.add(TXT)
End sub

End Class
```

But I can't access the `NSP` from the second subroutine. I get an error saying

> NSP is not declared

How do I solve this?

Comment: The error itself is easy to solve. See proposed duplicate for discussion on variable scoping in VB.NET. You've declared the variable in a method, which means it's visible _only in that method_. If you want to share a variable, you need to put it somewhere that both methods have access to. That said, you should never be creating a `StackPanel` in code-behind anyway. With WPF, your UI should all be declared in XAML. If you want a new `StackPanel` to appear every time a button is clicked, then you should create a collection in your view model (e.g. `ObservableCollection(Of T)`), that holds a ...

Comment: ... separate view model object type that describes the data you want to display in the `StackPanel`, declare a template in XAML for that separate view model object type that has the `StackPanel` in it, then bind the collection to some kind of `ItemsControl` (either that class itself, `ListBox`, or some other `ItemsControl` subclass), and let WPF create the `StackPanel` objects for you as you add view model objects to the collection.